# Can't call a method from another window in C# WPF

Tags: c#, class, methods

Ok, let's say I have two windows. In the first one I have a method

```
public void Test()
{
    Label.Content += " works";
}
```

And in the second one I call this method:

```
MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
mw.Test();
```

But nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Well, I am supposing that your MainWindow is already open, what your code does is create another MainWindow and try to execute a Method without showing it.  How is the second window created? it is created in the MainWindow Window?

Comment: Yes, it is. So, is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can assign the Owner to the window that was created in your MainWindow.

```
window.Owner = this; //This is added to the code that use to create your Window
```

Then you should be able to access it something like this.

```
((MainWindow)this.Owner).Test();
```

**MainWindow**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Window1 window = new Window1();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        window.Show();


    }

    public void Test()
    {
        label1.Content += " works";
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        window.Owner = this;
    }


}
```

**Second Window**

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MainWindow)this.Owner).Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: @MarkHall       Is there any workaround when using window.ShowDialog? The Loaded event fires after returning control to the main window in this case...

Comment: @pzogr Both windows are running on the same thread. If you use ShowDialog it creates a Modal window that will block any code from running in the owning window while the Modal window is open, this is by design. If the reason you are wanting a Modal window is to limit action on the owner, you may want to try setting the owners readonly property to true and use Show as in this example. Other than that, there is no other way that I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you try this way.

```
public string Test()
{

   return  "works";
}

 MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();


 // Your second form label.
 lblsecondwindow.Text = mw.Test();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating another object of `MainWindow` as below:

```
MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
```

instead of creating new `MainWindow` object use the existing one(i'm assuming that you had already created `MainWindow` object before).

Try This:

```
oldmaindwindow.Test();//here oldmainwindow is an old object of MainWindow
```

if you can show the fullcode it heps us.