# How to Execute Functions from the Main Window

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, window

Im developing a little game in WPF with C#. I have 2 Windows open at the same time, one window for player1 and one window for player2.

Now I want to start a function in player1 when I click a button in the window of player2.

I tried it with:

```
Player1 play1 = new Player1();
play1.Function();
```

Then it executes the function in a third new window. But i want to execute it in the first existing window. So how can I do that?

Comment: Hold a reference to the window `Player1` in `Player2`.

Comment: Ehm, how should I do that?

Comment: pass it to your `Player2` window. Create a constructor with a parameter oftype `Player1`.

Comment: I suggest you work with a kind of PlayerManager who is keeping track what is happening on the scenes and send messages (like events) from and to the players. Creates a more responsive (non-blocking) environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more options how to do that.
One is explained in this link: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20014728/cant-call-a-method-from-another-window-in-c-sharp-wpf)

Other is to pass reference from parent windows to the child window.

You define property Player1 in Player2 window like:

```
public class Player2 {
   public Player1 Parent {private set;get}

   public Player2(Player1 parent) {
      this.Parent = parent;
   }

   public void MyMethod() {
       Parent.CustomMethodCall();
   }
}
```

You create Player2 Object in Player1 window like:

```
var win = new Player2(this);
win.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The linked worked fine. But your Code solution doesn´t worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to use events to communicate from main window to sub windows. And methods in the sub-windows to listen the main window.

you have your PlayerWindow like where you expose some events. I also aded a method for communication in the other direction (main window -> player window)

```
public class PlayerWindow : window
{
   public event EventHandler UserClickedButton;

   //Here the function you call when the user click's a button
   OnClick()
   {
       //if someone is listening to the event, call it
       if(UserClickedButton != null)
          UserClieckedButton(this, EventArgs.Empty);
   }

   public void ShowSomeStuff(string stuff)
   {
      MyLabel.Content = stuff;
   }
}
```

Then you have your main window, that creates the two windows (one for each player) and listen for the events

```
public class MainWindow : Window
{
     public MainWindow()
     {
         //we create the first window
         PlayerWindow w1 = new PlayerWindow();
         //hook to the event
         w1.UserClickedButton += Player1Clicked;

         //same for player 2
         PlayerWindow w2 = new PlayerWindow();
         w2.UserClickedButton += Player2Clicked;

         //open the created windows
         w1.Show();
         w2.Show();
     }

     private void Player2Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         //Here your code when player 2 clicks.
         w1.ShowSomeStuff("The other player clicked!");
     }

     private void Player2Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         //Here your code when player 1 clicks.
         w2.ShowSomeStuff("The player 1 clicked!");
     }
}
```